# Could not load file or assembly ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib... When using nuGet package ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, sharpziplib, exceldatareader

Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.5.452, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Stack:

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.85.5.452, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>      Excel.Core.ZipWorker.Extract(Stream fileStream) +0
>      Excel.ExcelOpenXmlReader.Initialize(Stream fileStream) +78

[Asp.Net Mvc3 C#]

Using the NuGet Package ExcelDataReader I tried to simply open up a .xlsx file saved on the filesystem. Here is the code used:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/blank3.xlsx");
FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

Here is the website for the nuget package:
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

What gives? This should work without a hitch.

Comment: As one of the comments below suggests, just install/reinstall the SharpZipLib package using NuGet. That worked for me. These other ways of doing it are a little hacky, in my opinion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ran into the same issue; to resolve, I found the appropriate strong-name assembly on their codeplex project.

Downloaded the source code from http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com, grabbed the assembly from their LIB directory and referenced it from my project.

**Edit May 2021**
Looks like the link referenced is going away shortly; it's probably best (and easier) to follow [Oleg's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982394/1186321) below.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit with your process please?

Answer (score 5):

If what you are getting is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Then the solution is to download the [latest](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/DownloadLatestVersion.asp?what=BinDoc) (or choose the right [version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/SharpZipLib/) for your error) `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll` from the SharpZipLib [website](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx), and just place it in the folder where the ExcelDataReader's `Excel.dll` is located (no need to reference it).

Comment: wawwooow, Thank you very much, you just save a day! just what I was looking for. The exact way that guide was perfect and solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

because the dll is .net version 2.0, your project is higher,
if you install the package from nuget package manager,
it will auto use runtime assembly binding, the web.config/app.config file should like this:

```
  <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib" publicKeyToken="1b03e6acf1164f73" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.85.4.369" newVersion="0.85.4.369" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: simply: install the package from nuget package manager --- this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib is strong name assembly. Assembly version number must exactly match or otherwise it fails to load. Please check assembly version.

Comment: Where would I find the assembly? It is not included as any package or in my web.config file.